# Is there a way to plot a graph using multiple columns in data?

Tags: r, dataframe, graph

I have a EPL matches data loaded into R consisting of 4 columns (Home Team, Full Time Home Team Goals, Away Team, Full Time Away Team Goals).

Home Team and Away Team consists of a total of 20 football clubs.
I would like to plot a graph showing the total number of goals (both home team goals and away team goals) scored by each football club.
May I know the easiest way to go about this?

I'm new to R and can't quite figure out which way would be the best.
Do I create a data frame first and then plot a graph?
A part of my data as shown below;
[My data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzVlX.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question][1]
  

[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  
and 
[how to give a reproducible example][2] 

[2]:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example
.This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Without having the data, I would say that the easiest way is to create a data frame and create a new column grouping first by team name and adding up both home and away goals. Then you can just plot the total goals by each team.  If you provide a data example I can show you a code example.